# Can not access admin on Heroku

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, django-admin

So i pushed my Code to Heroku and I have a lot of trouble getting things to work. The Static files do not work, I installed WhiteNoise and so on but I break the site as soon as I use `{%static 'js/whatever.js'%}` but `{% load staticfiles %}` can be used without breaking the server. Currently my theory is that the admin won't load because of the static files but they are not required for the normal django admin right?

Here are my important lines I hope somebody finds the mistake. 
settings.py

- `DEBUG = False`
- `ALLOWED_HOSTS = [u'....herokuapp.com']`
- `import dj_database_url`
- `DATABASES ={'default':dj_database_url.parse('postgres://...jl4',conn_max_age=600)}`
- `INSTALLED_APPS = [`
  `'rest_framework',"rest_framework.authtoken",'django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth','django.contrib.staticfiles',]`
- `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS =('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)`
- `SITE_ID = 1`
- `WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ABC.wsgi.application'`
- `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
- `STATICFILES_DIRS =[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]`
- `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')`
- `STATICFILES_STORAGE ='whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

wsgi.py

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ABC.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
application.add_files('/ABC/static/', prefix='/static/')
```

Procfile file, requirements.txt, .git folder are present and look normal. I have no problems on 127.0.0.1 at all. No migration problems anywhere. Heroku is configured with a Python Buildpack and Postgres. 404 500 etc Handlers are installed and working (Btw I get a 500 Internal Server Error).

When I push the Code online with `DEBUG=True` (I know you should not do that but im totally frustrated), I have no Problems at all. Can Access the Admin and can Load the static files without any Problems.

So If anybody has an Idea whats missing please tell me. There are no stupid comments/questions I need answers!

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls import (
handler400, handler403, handler404, handler500
)

handler400 = 'my_profile.views.server_error'
handler403 = 'my_profile.views.server_error2'
handler404 = 'my_profile.views.server_error3'
handler500 = 'my_profile.views.server_error4'

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^my_profile/',include('my_profile.urls',namespace='my_profile')),
url(r'^login/',include('login.urls')),
url(r'^logout/',include('login.urls')),
url(r'^register/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
url(r'^userprofile/',include('userprofile.urls')),
url(r'^about/',include('about.urls')),
url('^inbox/notifications/',include(notifications.urls,namespace='notifications')),
```

Comment: Since everything works in DEBUG=True I think it is related to whitenoise. Could you also add your main urls.py? Another thing: what happens if you drop the last line from your wsgi.py file?

Comment: @dentemm when I delete the last line nothing happens. But good you mentioned it I added it there and totally forgot it exist.